# Clicking on a single button on table in a foreach loop not working

Tags: laravel, user-interface, foreach, html-table

I am working on a Laravel application whereby I have some data that is generated from the backend and am displaying on the view in the form of a table. On the table am doing a foreach loop inside the tbody whereby I display each row together with a button the user can click to submit the data of that particular row. The problem is that **when the user clicks on each button on the row nothing happens** but when I **change the html structure of the table the data gets submitted but  the table headers get mis-aligned henceforth destroying the User interface**

**1st layout which doesnt submit anything after a button is clicked**

```
<table class="table table-hover mg-b-0 tx-11" id="policyTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>INVOICE DATE</th>
    <th>VOUCHER NO.</th>
    <th>INVOICE AMOUNT</th>
    <th>KRA PIN</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
    <th>PAYOUT</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
   <tbody>
    @foreach($medical as $lifeC)
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('b2b.medPayout') }}" id="payoutRequest">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">  
        <tr>
            <!-- Hidden input fields that am submitting of a form that am submitting-->
             <input type="hidden" name="agentName" id="agentName" value="{{ $lifeC->agent_name }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="voucherNo" id="voucherNo" value="{{ $lifeC->voucher_number }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="agentCode" id="agentCode" value="{{ $lifeC->agent_code }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="kraPin" id="kraPin" value="{{ $lifeC->kra_pin }}">
            <!--END-->
            <td class="add-color-dark">{{ $lifeC->agent_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ date( 'M j, Y', strtotime($lifeC->invoice_date)) }}</td>
            <td>{{ $lifeC->voucher_number }}</td>
            <td>{{ $lifeC->invoice_amount }}</td>
            <td>{{ $lifeC->kra_pin }}</td>
            <td>
                <span class="badge badge-danger">{{ $lifeC->payment_status }}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnFront" style="cursor: pointer;"> Request </button>      
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>     
    @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

**2nd layout that submits but the thead are misaligned**

```
 <table class="table table-hover mg-b-0 tx-14">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>NAME</th>
    <th>INVOICE DATE</th>
    <th>VOUCHER NO.</th>
    <th>INVOICE AMOUNT</th>
    <th>KRA PIN</th>
    <th>STATUS</th>
    <th>PAYOUT</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
<tbody>
        @foreach($medical as $lifeC)
        <!--Add the table insode the form-->
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('b2b.medPayout') }}" id="payoutRequest">
          <table class="table table-hover mg-b-0 tx-11" id="policyTable">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">  
            <tr>
                 <input type="hidden" name="agentName" id="agentName" value="{{ $lifeC->agent_name }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="voucherNo" id="voucherNo" value="{{ $lifeC->voucher_number }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="agentCode" id="agentCode" value="{{ $lifeC->agent_code }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="kraPin" id="kraPin" value="{{ $lifeC->kra_pin }}">

                <td class="add-color-dark">{{ $lifeC->agent_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ date( 'M j, Y', strtotime($lifeC->invoice_date)) }}</td>
                <td>{{ $lifeC->voucher_number }}</td>
                <td>{{ $lifeC->invoice_amount }}</td>
                <td>{{ $lifeC->kra_pin }}</td>
                <td>
                    <span class="badge badge-danger">{{ $lifeC->payment_status }}</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btnFront" style="cursor: pointer;"> Request </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>     
        @endforeach
</tbody>
```

**Screenshot[image: Misaligned header]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to do it this way, you will need to make the IDs unique for your fields. I suggest dynamically setting them with a unique value for each row, something like:

`id="payoutRequest_$lifeC->agent_id"`

for every value that has an ID. IDs should always be unique - this means that for each iteration of your loop, the buttons and data being submitted will be unique to that specific row.

Comment: Hi,,, I have tried implementing your suggestion on the **1st layout** I posted above using this code `<input type="hidden" name="rowId" id="{{ $lifeC->voucher_number }}" value="{{ $lifeC->voucher_number }}">` which is unique among the form input fields but it still doesnt submit

Comment: Thanks man. I had the same problem. i had to make each id's unque

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you recreate your layout and use ajax instead.

With your current layout, not only you are repeating too many `input type hidden`, but also the `<form>` gets repeated each loop and all has the same `id`(even the buttons, inputs etc).

Try changing your button to something that passes data based on what row the button is located.